$|f(x)-f(y)| < |g(x) - g(y)|$ when $|f'| < |g'|$
Let $f, g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be differentiable. Suppose that $|f'(x)| < |g'(x)|$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. The goal is to prove that $|f(x) - f(y)| < |g(x) - g(y)|$ for $x, y \in \mathbb R$ with $x \ne y$.
By the Darboux theorem, $g'$ must be either positive or negative everywhere. With extra assumptions that $f, g$ are absolutely continuous on every compact interval (e.g. holds when $f', g'$ are bounded on every compact interval), the desired result follows by the fundamental theorem of Calculus for Lebesgue integrals.
Here are my questions:
(1) Is the statement true without the additional assumptions? If so, what would be a proof?
(2) In case it is true, is there a "short" proof of the statement without using any measure theory?
I would appreciate any hint or reference.

Fix $x<y$. By Cauchy’s mean-value theorem (which is completely elementary, and is simply a “clever” application of the usual mean-value theorem), there is a number $\xi\in (x,y)$ such that
\begin{align}
[f(x)-f(y)]\cdot g’(\xi)&=[g(x)-g(y)]\cdot f’(\xi).
\end{align}
Taking absolute values and dividing (division is justified since our hypothesis tells us $g’(\xi)\neq 0$) gives
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=|g(x)-g(y)|\cdot \frac{|f’(\xi)|}{|g’(\xi)|}\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
The fraction is strictly less than $1$ by assumption. Also, our hypothesis tells us that $g’$ is nowhere vanishing, so by the mean-value theorem, $g(x)-g(y)=g’(\zeta)\cdot (x-y)$ for some (other) $\zeta\in (x,y)$, so in particular $g(x)-g(y)\neq 0$. Thus, in $(*)$ we have on the right a positive number being multiplied by something in $[0,1)$, so we deduce
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)|<|g(x)-g(y)|.
\end{align}
